# Proving that a function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is bijective and find the inverse

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that the function $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(x+iy) = x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} ) $ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ is bijective and find its inverse.

**My approach:** For to prove that $f$ is injective, we need to show that if $z_{1},z_{2} \in \mathbb{C}$, $$f(z_{2})=f(z_{1}) \implies z_{1}=z_{2}$$
Suppose that $a+bi,c+di \in \mathbb{C}$ and that $f(a+bi)=f(c+di )$, so we have $$a+(-1)^{\lfloor b\rfloor}+i(b+(-1)^{\lfloor a \rfloor})=c+(-1)^{\lfloor d\rfloor}+i(d+(-1)^{\lfloor c \rfloor}) \implies \left\{ \begin{aligned} a+(-1)^{\lfloor b\rfloor}=c+(-1)^{\lfloor d\rfloor} \\ b+(-1)^{\lfloor a \rfloor}=d+(-1)^{\lfloor c \rfloor} \end{aligned}\right. \implies \left\{\begin{aligned} a=c \\ b=d \end{aligned}  \right.$$ so $f$ is injective.

Now, for to prove that $f$ is surjective we need to prove that if $c+di \in \mathbb{C}$, so there exists a $a+bi \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(a+bi)=c+di$, but it's it immediate? Isn't it just, for example, taking $a+bi=c+di$ and Q.E.D?

---

How can I prove that $f$ is surjective and how can I find the inverse of the funcion?

Comment: It is not clear from what you've written that your last implication (the one ending with $\implies a = c \text{ and } b = d$) is true. Please provide more detail

Comment: It might be more work than is necessary to actually prove injectivity and surjectivity directly. You can instead just construct an inverse function, i.e. define a function $g: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(g(z)) = g(f(z)) = z$

Comment: Maybe try an explicit example first: Can you find $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x + iy) = 2.4 - 1.7i$?

Comment: Nope. To show surjective you have to show that given any `a` and `b`  in `a+bi` they can be written as $x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} )$ for some `x` and `y`

Comment: You're right. I think we need to work more for to prove the injective. For a moment I thought it was immediate, but it seems not.

Comment: Try doing it in four stages. Case1: a and b are even integers, Case2: a is even and b is odd, ...

Comment: @AvenDesta A function $f: X \to Y$ is surjective if $\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X: f(x)=y$.

Comment: @АлександрПальма Yes. thats what I said.

Comment: @AvenDesta Can you write a post with a more details explications of your hints? Thank you so much.

Comment: @АлександрПальма IMO it's your turn to do some work. To Aven's point, start with solving the equation $f(z) = a + bi$ in the case that $a, b$ are even integers. Then proceed to the other cases

Comment: @AlexG. Just right now, I'm trying to solve the problem using the hint of Aven.

Comment: @АлександрПальма Please upvote my answer if it helped you! thanks

Comment: @AvenDesta Thank so much. I'm going to try finished the problem.

Comment: @АлександрПальма already done. good luck

Answer (score 1):

To show surjective you have to show that given any $a$ and $b$  in $a+ib$ they can be written as
$$x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} )$$
for some $x$ and $y$

Case 1: Both $a$ and $b$ are even integers.

Then take $x = a+1$, $y=b+1$. (Then $x$ and $y$ are both odd).

This is a solution because
$$x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} )$$
$$=(x - 1) + i(y - 1)$$
$$=(a)+i(b)$$

Case 2: $a$ is even integer and $b$ is odd integer.

Then take $x = a-1$, $y=b+1$. (Then $x$ is odd and $y$ is even).

This is a solution because
$$x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} )$$
$$=(x + 1) + i(y - 1)$$
$$=(a)+i(b)$$

Case 3: $a$ is odd integer and $b$ is even integer.

Then take $x = a+1$, $y=b-1$. (Then $x$ is even and $y$ is odd).

This is a solution because
$$x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} )$$
$$=(x - 1) + i(y + 1)$$
$$=(a)+i(b)$$

Case 4: Both $a$ and $b$ are odd integers.

Then take $x = a-1$, $y=b-1$. (Then $x$ and $y$ are both even).

This is a solution because
$$x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} + i(y + (-1)^{ \lfloor x \rfloor} )$$
$$=(x + 1) + i(y + 1)$$
$$=(a)+i(b)$$

Hence, we conclude:

For any $a+ib$ from the range of $f$ we can find $x+iy$ from the domain of $f$ such that $a+ib = f(x+iy)$

Comment: Correction to case 1: $x$ and $y$ are odd, so $x + (-1)^{\lfloor y \rfloor} = x - 1$, not $x+1$. You want to use $x = a+1$, $y=b+1$ instead.

Comment: Александр Пальма, please upvote if you find my answer useful.